# How to calculate zonal statistics from multi-band raster for each polygon using python?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I want to calculate the zonal statastics from multi band raster for a polygon layer. When I am using this snippet of code:

```
vectorlayer=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()
zonalstats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vectorlayer,rasterfile,"Zonal_")
zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)
```

it is updating the field names but the values are **NULL** in the attribute table. So if I want to get the values to be updated, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're getting *NULL* values but the following code worked for me (*note that I call the QGIS Zonal Statistics tool from the **Processing** plugin* and I want to load the result):

```
vectorlayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()
processing.runandload('qgis:zonalstatistics', rasterfile, 3, vectorlayer, "Zonal_", True, None)
```

The following is the *help description* for the parameters required which you can edit in your code:

```
>>>processing.alghelp("qgis:zonalstatistics")
    ALGORITHM: Zonal Statistics
        INPUT_RASTER <ParameterRaster>
        RASTER_BAND <ParameterNumber>
        INPUT_VECTOR <ParameterVector>
        COLUMN_PREFIX <ParameterString>
        GLOBAL_EXTENT <ParameterBoolean>
        OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: will the Zonal statastics work for multi band raster?

Comment: @user99 - I believe so yes since you can specify the number of _Raster bands_ required (I used `3` in the code).

Comment: is there any other way to calculate the raster statastics instead of Zonal?

Comment: @user99 - There's the _Raster layer statistics_ tool which gives you the basic statistics: `max`, `min`, `sum`, `mean`, and `std dev`. Are there any specific statistics you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution which I derived from running through the Zonal Statistics plugin wizard and viewing the generated Python command with Advanced -> Copy as Python Command.
Then simply adding a loop to support the multiband requirement.

```
for i in range(1,num_raster_bands):
    processing.run("native:zonalstatisticsfb", { 
        'INPUT':'my_shp_file',
        'INPUT_RASTER':'my_raster_file',
        'RASTER_BAND':i,
        'COLUMN_PREFIX':'_',
        'STATISTICS':[0,1,2],
        'OUTPUT':f'output_filepath_{i}.csv'
})
```