# Writing result of PyQGIS to shapefile

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I try to perform some zonal statistics on a shape- and rasterfile and write the output to a completely new shapefile!

```
import sys
# where is the module
sys.path.append("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/")
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')

import gdal
from qgis.analysis import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# initialize application
qpp = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# rasterfile
filename = "/.../200001.asc"

vLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/.../my.shp", "plz", "ogr")
print vLayer.isValid()
> true

# zonal statistics
zonalStats = QgsZonalStatistics(vLayer, filename, 'pre-', 1)
zonalStats.calculateStatistics(None)
print zonalStats
> <qgis._analysis.QgsZonalStatistics object at 0x10cdf9e90>

# write shp
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(zonalStats, "/.../zonal.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

That returns.

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>
> QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(QgsVectorLayer, QString, QString, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QString driverName="ESRI Shapefile", bool onlySelected=False, QString errorMessage=None, QStringList datasourceOptions=QStringList(), QStringList layerOptions=QStringList(), bool skipAttributeCreation=False, QString newFilename=None, QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology, float symbologyScale=1, QgsRectangle filterExtent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsZonalStatistics'
>     QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(QgsVectorLayer, QString, QString, QgsCoordinateTransform, QString driverName="ESRI Shapefile", bool onlySelected=False, QString errorMessage=None, QStringList datasourceOptions=QStringList(), QStringList layerOptions=QStringList(), bool skipAttributeCreation=False, QString newFilename=None, QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology, float symbologyScale=1, QgsRectangle filterExtent=None):
>
> argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsZonalStatistics'

I assume that `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` needs something different than an object of type `'QgsZonalStatistics'`. But how would I write my `shp` then?

I also tried

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(QString(zonalStats), "/.../zonal.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

which returned

> NameError: name 'QString' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use  `QgsZonalStatistics`, the results are are automatically added to the shapefile (look at [Problem with calculating QGIS Zonal Statistics MEAN](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181329/2581) or [Estadística zonal con PyQGIS: clase QgsZonalStatistics](https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/estadistica-zonal-con-pyqgis-clase-qgszonalstatistics/))

```
 vLayer = QgsVectorLayer("a_polygon.shp","a_polygon.shp","ogr")
 path = "test.tif"
 zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics(vLayer, path,"", 1, QgsZonalStatistics.All)
 zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

Detail

[image]

If you examine the functions in ZoneStat with [see](https://github.com/inky/see) (equivalent of `dir`)

```
 from see import see
 see(zoneStat)
 hash()           help()           repr()           str()            .All
.Count           .Majority        .Max             .Mean
.Median          .Min             .Minority        .Range           .StDev
.Statistic()     .Statistics()    .Sum             .Variety
.calculateStatistics()
```

And I did not understand how do we get the values ([QGIS Zonal Stats Plugin - Python Console - compute one specific statistic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178898/2581), [QgsZonalStatistics Class Reference](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsZonalStatistics.html))

```
 zoneStat.Count
 1 # -> it's part of an enumeration 
 zoneStat.Mean
 4 # -> it's part of an enumeration
```

You can also use the QGIS Zonal Statistics tool from the Processing plugin (look at [How to calculate zonal statistics from multi-band raster for each polygon using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155693/2581)

But I also do not understand why you use QGIS from outside when there are pure Python modules for that as [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) with **one polygon** here

[image]

```
 from rasterstats import zonal_stats
 stats = zonal_stats("a_polygon.shp", "test.asc")
 print stats
 [{'count': 398, 'max': 261.95001220703125, 'mean': 227.95232019472363, 'min': 194.2899932861328}]
 print stats[0]['mean']
 227.952320195
 mean = stats[0]['mean']
```

And you can use [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) to save the result to a new shapefile without the "complications" of PyQGIS from outside

```
 with fiona.open("a_polygon.shp") as input:
    # add the mean field to the schema of the resulting shapefile
    schema = input.schema
    schema['properties']['mean'] = 'float:10.4'
    with fiona.open('result.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
        for feature in input:
            feature['properties']['mean']= mean
            output.write(feature)
```

#### New

If there are two or many polygons in the shapefile,

[image]

the results are for example

```
stats = zonal_stats("polygons.shp", "test.asc")
[{'count': 398, 'max': 261.95001220703125, 'mean': 227.95232019472363, 'min': 194.2899932861328}, {'count': 267, 'max': 246.6300048828125, 'mean': 222.61079412453182, 'min': 197.07000732421875},....]
means = [stat['mean'] for stat in stats]
print means
[227.95232019472363, 222.61079412453182....]
```

And

```
with fiona.open("polygons.shp") as input:
    # add the mean field to the schema of the resulting shapefile
    schema = input.schema
    schema['properties']['mean'] = 'float:10.4'
    with fiona.open('result2.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
        for i, feature in enumerate(input):
            feature['properties']['mean']= means[i]
            output.write(feature)
```

Comment: btw your code is not working. Your `rasterstats` `fiona` example attaches to each cell the same value, namely the first value of `stats[0]['mean']`. It does not iterate through the results of ` stats = zonal_stats("a_polygon.shp", "test.asc")`. I also wonder how `fiona` would know where to assign the results of ` stats = zonal_stats("a_polygon.shp", "test.asc")` to?! That is no where stored with a `key` or something.

Comment: I don't accept your suggestion because there is only one polygon in my layer and the values `stats[0]['mean']`comes from rasterstat (one polygon = one value). I adapted the scripts for many polygons above

Comment: gene, so true. Totally forgot about that. Your right! However, how does `fiona` know which values to use from the dictionary, created by `rasterstats`?

Comment: with `enumerate(list)`