# Writing geoJson from rasterstats

Tags: python, geojson, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

How would I write a proper `geoJson`, readable by a GIS, from the results of the [rasterstats](http://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html) package?

```
stats = zonal_stats("somePolygons.shp",
                     "someTif.tif",
                    geojson_out=True)
```

Something like

```
import geojson
with open("newfile.geojson", "w") as myFile:
     myfile.write(geojson.dump(stats))
```

does not work. 
The object I am getting from `rasterstats` is a `geoJson`. There are 200 Polygons in my `geoJson` object. 
Do I really have to write my `geoJson` "manually" like suggested in an answere [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/generating-geojson-with-python), or is there a way to do that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a basic [Python json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) problem ([How do I write JSON data to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309296/835653))

```
 from rasterstats import zonal_stats
 stats = zonal_stats("a_poly.shp", "test.tif",geojson_out=True))
 # as the result is a json/geojson object
 import json # or geojson
 with open('newfile.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(stats, outfile) # or geojson.dump(stats, outfile)
```

Look also at [Writing result of PyQGIS to shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191041/2581)

#### New

If is is for a GIS, you need a type [Feature](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects) or [FeatureCollection](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects) (dictionary with key `Feature` or `FeatureCollection`)

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
stats = zonal_stats("a_poly.shp", "test.tif",geojson_out=True))
result = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": stats}
import json # or geojson
with open('newfile.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(result, outfile) # or geojson.dump(result, outfile)
```

Comment: that one I tried too but when I try to import the file created like `geojson.dump(stats, outfile)` into `QGIS` I get the message that this is not a `valid layer`...

Comment: look above in my answer